# Set image & text downloaded from server as app icon & name in Android

Tags: android, icons

I want to change the app icon and app name on Android programmatically after getting the icon and name from server.

Please note that I need to change the app icon and name in runtime. These two are fetched from a server. So I cannot use methods involving setting icons and names in AndroidManifest.xml as it requires that you know your app name and icon in advance.

Do anyone know how to do that? Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: Try DivKit https://github.com/divkit/divkit

Comment: @VivekGupta It does not seem to be what I need. While it allows us to update the UI in accordance with the changes on server, I still can't find a way to use the library to set a drawable file as app icon & name without touching AndroidManifest.xml programmatically